# How to sorting date time in string array php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to sorting date time in a string array using php. My string look like this, I want to sorting first date and time. For ex. 14_04_2016 (date) and 01_00pm_03_00pm (Time will be first and second 15_04_2016...) like that..

Any body have idea please suggest me..

Thanks in advance.

String Array:
    [0] => 05_00pm_07_00pm|15_04_2016 
    [1] => 03_00pm_05_00pm|15_04_2016
    [2] => 07_00pm_09_00pm|15_04_2016
    [3] => 03_00pm_05_00pm|14_04_2016
    [4] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|14_04_2016
    [5] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016
    [6] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016
    [7] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016
    [8] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016
    [9] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016
    [10] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016
    [11] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016
    [12] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016
    [13] => 07_00pm_09_00pm|14_04_2016
    [14] => 07_00pm_09_00pm|16_04_2016
    [15] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|14_04_2016
    [16] => 07_00pm_09_00pm|13_04_2016

Comment: Please show ur try. @Naeem Sabasara

Comment: @ Ruchish, I am doing a explode both the values and trying with multi sort..

Comment: yes correct. @Naeem Sabasara

Comment: Should you require code?

Comment: Yes, i require the code... I am trying with explode and doing sorting with multi sort function but not getting properly result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one it will work for you.

```
$array= Array(
    0 => '05_00pm_07_00pm|15_04_2016',1 => '03_00pm_05_00pm|15_04_2016',2 => '07_00pm_09_00pm|15_04_2016',3 => '03_00pm_05_00pm|14_04_2016',
    4 => '01_00pm_03_00pm|14_04_2016',5 => '01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016',6 => '01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016',7 => '01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016',
    8 => '01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016',9 => '01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016',10 => '01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016',11 => '01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016',
    12 => '01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016',13 => '07_00pm_09_00pm|14_04_2016',14 => '07_00pm_09_00pm|16_04_2016',15 => '01_00pm_03_00pm|14_04_2016',
    16 => '07_00pm_09_00pm|13_04_2016'
);
foreach($array as $key=>$row)
{
    $newArr[$key] = explode("|", $row);
    $timeArray[] = $newArr[$key][0];
    $dateArray[] = $newArr[$key][1];
}   

array_multisort($dateArray, SORT_ASC, $timeArray, SORT_ASC, $newArr);

$finalArray = array();
foreach($newArr as $key1=>$row1)
{
    $finalArray[] = implode("|",$row1);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($finalArray);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 07_00pm_09_00pm|13_04_2016
    [1] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|14_04_2016
    [2] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|14_04_2016
    [3] => 03_00pm_05_00pm|14_04_2016
    [4] => 07_00pm_09_00pm|14_04_2016
    [5] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016
    [6] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016
    [7] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016
    [8] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016
    [9] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016
    [10] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016
    [11] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016
    [12] => 01_00pm_03_00pm|15_04_2016
    [13] => 03_00pm_05_00pm|15_04_2016
    [14] => 05_00pm_07_00pm|15_04_2016
    [15] => 07_00pm_09_00pm|15_04_2016
    [16] => 07_00pm_09_00pm|16_04_2016
)
```

**Also check in Online Editor. [Click Here](https://eval.in/553209)**

Comment: Yes, That's the great.. I got a proper results.. My mistake is i was not imploding a value, i am doing a direct fetch the value... <br/> Thanks a lot !!!!!

Comment: Welcome. Glad to help you.